# How do I force VMWare to pause/suspend guest when host put to sleep?

Tags: windows, macos, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I have a VMWare Fusion 8.5 virtual machine running Windows 10 (guest) running on macOS 10.11/El Capitan (host).

When the host goes to sleep — usually because I close the MacBook Pro's lid — the virtual machine shuts down. Or more specifically, when I wake up my MacBook Pro, I discover that the VM is no longer running, and I'm required to start it up again.

I don't recall this issue when I used VMs in the past on this same laptop. However, since that time, I probably upgraded my VMWare software. I cannot locate any obvious settings/preferences that will fix the problem.

FWIW, I did tweak the Power & Sleep settings on the Windows 10 guest recently so the Screen and PC, respectively, would "never" turn off or go to sleep. I did this to address a separate issue. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether current problem was occurring before that time or not.